# How to jump character with using JoyStick in Mobile Touch Screen?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touchscreen, joystick

I want to jump and move my character at the same with using just one Joystick. Is there any idea?

In my joystick;

- Left key will allow character to move left.
- Right key will allow character to move right.
- Up key will allow character to **JUMP**.

Currently, my character moves left and right easily with using CrossPlatformInput. But I want add a jump feature to the up-key of the joystick. I don't want to use any extra jump button.

[image]

Here is my codes for moving character

```
 public class Platformer2DUserControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlatformerCharacter2D m_Character;
    private bool m_Jump;


    private void Awake()
    {
        m_Character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (!m_Jump)
        {
            // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
            m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
        }
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Read the inputs.
        bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
        float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
        m_Character.Move(h, crouch, m_Jump);
        m_Jump = false;
    }
}
```

And the other one;

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        // Setting up references.
        m_GroundCheck = transform.Find("GroundCheck");
        m_CeilingCheck = transform.Find("CeilingCheck");
        m_Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        m_Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerGraphics = transform.FindChild("Graphics");
        if (playerGraphics == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("There is no 'Graphics' object as a child of the player");
        }
    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        bool wasGrounded = m_Grounded;
        m_Grounded = false;

        // The player is grounded if a circlecast to the groundcheck position hits anything designated as ground
        // This can be done using layers instead but Sample Assets will not overwrite your project settings.
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(m_GroundCheck.position, k_GroundedRadius, m_WhatIsGround);
        for (int i = 0; i < colliders.Length; i++)
        {
            if (colliders[i].gameObject != gameObject)
                m_Grounded = true;
        }
        m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", m_Grounded);
        // Set the vertical animation
        m_Anim.SetFloat("vSpeed", m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }


    public void Move(float move, bool crouch, bool jump)
    {
        // If crouching, check to see if the character can stand up
        if (!crouch && m_Anim.GetBool("Crouch"))
        {
            // If the character has a ceiling preventing them from standing up, keep them crouching
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(m_CeilingCheck.position, k_CeilingRadius, m_WhatIsGround))
            {
                crouch = true;
            }
        }

        // Set whether or not the character is crouching in the animator
        m_Anim.SetBool("Crouch", crouch);

        //only control the player if grounded or airControl is turned on
        if (m_Grounded || m_AirControl)
        {
            // Reduce the speed if crouching by the crouchSpeed multiplier
            move = (crouch ? move * m_CrouchSpeed : move);

            // The Speed animator parameter is set to the absolute value of the horizontal input.
            m_Anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));

            // Move the character
            m_Rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * m_MaxSpeed, m_Rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

            // If the input is moving the player right and the player is facing left...
            if (move > 0 && !m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
            // Otherwise if the input is moving the player left and the player is facing right...
            else if (move < 0 && m_FacingRight)
            {
                // ... flip the player.
                Flip();
            }
        }
        // If the player should jump...
        if (m_Grounded && jump && m_Anim.GetBool("Ground"))
        {
            // Add a vertical force to the player.
            m_Grounded = false;
            m_Anim.SetBool("Ground", false);
            m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));
        }
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
        m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

        // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
        Vector3 theScale = playerGraphics.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        playerGraphics.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");` is for moving **left** and **right** then `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Vertical");`  is for moving **up** and **down**.

When `CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Vertical");` returns value that is `> 0`, then it is up. Any value that `< 0` is down. When `0`, it means that it is not moving up or down.

Replace the `Update()` function in the first Script in your question with the code below.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (!m_Jump)
    {
        //Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
        //m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");

        float checkJump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        if(checkJump>0.3f){
          //Up
           m_Jump = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Programmer, I tried what you have offered, it is working, but it jumps with too much force. You have any idea how can I limit this?

Comment: @komtan yes,  it is in your second code. There is this line `m_Rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, m_JumpForce));` Change the `m_JumpForce` value to something lower than what it is now. You did not put how it is defined.  Just Keep lowering it until you like the height of the jump.